# Creating default object from empty value PHP

Tags: php, json, poo, jsonobject

Desde hace unas horas empezó a salir un error en mi app, no entiendo que puede estar fallando, nunca entendí mucho el manejo de objetos en PHP pero la verdad que ahora me mato, busque varias soluciones posible en internet pero no puedo entender en que estoy fallando.
El script debería de devolver un Objeto JSON , que antes lo hacia pero ahora dejo de funcionar solo.

Debería de devolver:

```
{"kdt":{"1":{"kdtRow":"(071) - Mars  (moto)"}}}
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in <b>/home/c1851041/public_html/app/api.php</b> on line <b>447</b><br />
```

Mi script:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$bl = $cnn->prepare('SELECT * FROM kdts WHERE activo=1 and tipo=1 and libre=1 and estado=1 order by kdt asc');
$bl->execute();
$i=0;
foreach ($bl as $row)
    {
        $i++;
        $myObj->kdtRow = "(".str_pad($row['kdt'], 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).") - ".$row['nombre']."  (".$row['typeVehi'].")";
    }
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

Alguno le ha pasado?, busco y busco pero no encuentro nada que me ayude a entender lo que sucede.

Comment: Probé iniciar la variable $myObj pero sigo sin tener resultados. Creo que el problema radica en que son 3 objetos uno dentro del otro.

Answer (score 1):

Es una advertencia de PHP la cual te está advirtiendo que la variable **$myObj** no está inicializada. Puedes deshabilitar la salida de errores y advertencias con la función [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

O en su defecto inicializar dicha variable.

```
$myObj = new stdClass;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lei eso en varios lugares, el problema es que yo tengo 3 objetos uno dentro del otro, los cuales son cargados dentro de un for, entonces no puedo iniciar las 3 variables, probé de mil maneras pero singuen sin salir los resultados.

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es usar un array que almacene dichos objetos. Creo que sería lo más acertado en tu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Debes inicializar el objeto y cada elemento para poder usarlos y, además, crear la estructura como la quieres:

```
objeto
  -> kdt (otro objeto)
    -> Número (otro objeto)
      -> kdtRow (cadena)
```

También debes tener en cuenta cómo crear y acceder a propiedades:

- Alfanumérica: $objeto->nombreDePropiedad
- Numérica:

  - Con número: $objeto->{'1'}
  - Con variable: $objeto->{"$nombreDeVariable"}

```
// Solo como ejemplo
$bl = [
    ['kdt' => 71, 'nombre' => 'Mars', 'typeVehi' => 'Moto']
];

// Inicializar objeto
$myObj = new stdClass();
// Inicializar propiedad kdt
$myObj->kdt = new stdClass();
// Inicializar contador
$i = 0;
foreach ($bl as $row)
{
    // Incrementar contador, no le veo sentido, pero así lo quieres
    $i++;
    // Inicializar elemento del índice actual ($i)
    $myObj->kdt->{"$i"} = new stdClass();
    // Asignar propiedad kdtRow
    $myObj->kdt->{"$i"}->kdtRow = "(".str_pad($row['kdt'], 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).") - ".$row['nombre']."  (".$row['typeVehi'].")";
}
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

Resultado:

```
{"kdt":{"1":{"kdtRow":"(071) - Mars (Moto)"}}}
```

Usando arreglos en vez de objetos puede ser más sencillo y se obtiene el mismo resultado:

```
// Inicializar arreglo
$myObj = [];
// Crear arreglo para kdt
$myObj['kdt'] = [];
// Inicializar contador
$i = 0;
foreach ($bl as $row)
{
    // Incrementar contador
    $i++;
    // Insertar línea actual con índice $i
    $myObj['kdt'][$i] = ['kdtRow' => "(".str_pad($row['kdt'], 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).") - ".$row['nombre']."  (".$row['typeVehi'].")"];
}
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```